# Enumerating, and printing lines in Python.

Tags: python-3.x, enumeration

Okay, I am building a little program that will help single out Nmap results:

```
#Python3.7.x
#
#
#
#report=input('Name of the file of Nmap Scan:\n')
#target_ip=input('Which target is the report needed on?:\n')
report = "ScanTest.txt"
target_ip = "10.10.100.1"
begins = "Nmap scan report for"
fhand = open(report,'r')
beginsend = "Network Distance:"

for num1,line in enumerate(fhand, 1):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith(begins) and line.endswith(target_ip):
    print(num1)
for num2,line in enumerate(fhand, 1):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith(beginsend):
        print(num2)
```

In my what im trying to do is get the first part of the scan results "target_ip" and with that i hope i can read the lines from there until there is a break in the line of the txt.
What this code does for me now is just get me the line number where i want to start. 
In the second part of the code I tried getting the number of line for the last bit of text that i need. But it wont print. Im not sure if im going about this the right way or im not looking hard enough.
  In short find my line and print until there is a break in the text.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop exhausts all the lines in the file.  When the second loop tries to run, there are no more lines to read and the loop exits immediately.

If you want the first loop to stop when it finds a matching line and allow the second loop to read the remaining lines, you can add a `break` statement in the `if`.

```
start_pattern = 'hello there'
end_pattern = 'goodblye now'
print_flag = False

with open('somefile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if start_pattern in line:
            print_flag = True

        if print_flag:
            print line

        if end_pattern in line:
            break
```

Comment: Thanks John! that got me moving again. If i wanted to print the line again say print the enumerated line is there another function to use?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question -- wouldn't you just use `print()`?

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to print a series of lines starting from a condition defined from the user and a static condition (the end of the report for that particular il address)

Comment: Still not sure I understand the difficulty.  Read lines until you match the starting condition, keep reading and printing, then stop when you match the ending condition.

Comment: Yes! That is a much better way to put it. Which functions would help me with that? Read.lines?

Comment: If you just want to read each line in the file, `for line in file:` is the usual way to do it.

Comment: for line.startswith(text) print until \n   lol that is basically what im looking for i just dont know how to put it together.